# Are there any custom field types, besides Matrix, that allow you to create an updatable, non-finite list of things?

Tags: custom-fields, matrix, fieldtype

One of my main use cases for Matrix is when I need to manage a non-finite list of things related to an entry (e.g. translation links for articles may trickle in over time, and there's no pre-defined list of sources of them).

Sometimes Matrix feels like overkill, so I'm wondering what other folks use for this purpose.

Edited:

Someone mentioned Pixel & Tonic's List, which is a good one for my translation links use case; it's available in their Dive Bar: http://pixelandtonic.com/divebar

Another common use case is images: how do you allow users to add a non-finite set of images to an entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Grid Lite](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/grid-lite) is pretty similar to Matrix, and free. So if you're using matrix solely for translation links, this seems perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at Content Elements? http://dvt.ee/ad0g9RJ

Comment: Holy cow, I hadn't seen this. It's not quite what I need for this particular question, but I'm going to seriously look at this as a possible replacement for a generic "content" field for articles.

Comment: re-reading your OP I see where I misunderstood. I thought you had variable (unknown) content types within the same entry.