# Looking for a Matrix-like add-on which allows large textareas

Tags: add-on, matrix

I'm looking for an add-on that gives me a custom field with the "unlimited rows" aspect of Matrix, but I don't need the columns or need to specify additional fieldypes.

Is there an add-on that would allow me to add an arbitrary number of free-form chunks of data to an entry?

Updated to say: I'm looking to be able to add unlimited new textareas to an entry, in which I need to enter editable text. The limited size of Matrix/Grid Lite/P&T List fields don't quite work (but I'll fall back to Matrix if nothing else works out).

Comment: possible duplicates: [Are there any custom field types, besides Matrix, that allow you to create an updatable, non-finite list of things?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/are-there-any-custom-field-types-besides-matrix-that-allow-you-to-create-an-up) and [Repeating field without using Matrix](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2253/repeating-field-without-using-matrix/2257)

Comment: yeah, the previous question has the same answers, but unfortunately unsatisfying :)

Answer (score 1):

[Grid Lite](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/grid-lite) may be of use to you. (I haven't tried it though)

Also, I think [Objective HTML](https://objectivehtml.com/) may be working on a table-esque fieldtype.

Comment: Grid Lite seems to have the same issues I have with Matrix in that it simply offers more than I need. Was hoping to find a way to bascialy say "Give me a another textarea. Now another."

Comment: Can't you just set one column with the fieldtype as text?

Answer (score 1):

Would [P&T List](http://pixelandtonic.com/divebar) meet your project's needs?

Comment: Yes conceptually, but not in practice since I need a bigger field to work in.

Comment: Matrix, with one column and fieldtype Textarea would likely do it for you.  You can keep it simple but still have the other functionality available.  Just a thought since the other suggestions don't meet your needs.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what I'll end up doing. But you can't set the height of the text fields in Matrix (or can you) and I'm looking for enough room to edit code samples.

Comment: Yes, you would choose the "Text" type and hit the checkbox for "multiline".

Comment: Oh interesting — I knew about the multiline option, but I didn't realize while in use it expanded to fit the content you entered into it. That probably works for me.